# GetSystemDefaultLCID returns wrong data C++

Tags: c++, windows

I want to get the language of the OS, not the regional settings language. I used `GetSystemDefaultLCID()`, but it seems that it returns wrong data. My applications runs from a scheduled task under `SYSTEM` account, but it doesn't returns the language of the OS, it will return another language. So for example, i have a Windows XP Professional x64 Edition OS installed (which language is English), and my applications says that the language of this OS is hungarian (because the regional settings are hungarian).

Does anyones has any idea how could i get the correct language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GetSystemDefaultUILanguage
```

.
.